# Prevent iOS UIWebview page reload with 'Back' button

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview with a 'Back' button.

Whenever it is pressed the previous page completely loads again, making navigation sluggish. As part of the reloading it also scrolls to the top again so you have to scroll back down to where you were.

How do I prevent the page from reloading and just show what was previously there?

If someone clicks an actual link to go to a previously visited webpage then it should, of course, load that page again.

Comment: If you build your app for iOS 8.0 and later you can try to use WKWebView (new Apple native webView).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `UIWebView` reloads the page by default, however, depending on how you are presenting it, it may want to reload on, say, layout changes. If this is the case, you can try doing something like:

```
if webView.loading {
    webView.stopLoading()
}
```

...every time you update the layout and do not expect it to reload its contents. Updating layout may happen, say, when you present the view controller with a `UIWebView` to the user; or when orientation changes, updating `UIWebView`'s bounds. Alternatively, if you are anywhere near `UIWebView`'s delegate, return `false` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` callback instead of calling `stopLoading()`.